# In R, using geom_sf + frame and passing it to plotly::ggplotly gives me transitions error, what did I miss?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, transition, r-sf

I´m trying to make a **choropleth map with transitions** (*frames*) of quarterly unemployment data. The ggplot2 map seams fine, but the transitions between the frames in plotly are not. They should just change color (based on a change in the value for that state in the new quarter), but the process of rendering each frame is merging states (by color) or something like it.

I was unable to find the solution. Any clues on this behavior and possible solution?

I follow (mostly) this nice walkthrough: https://moderndata.plot.ly/learning-from-and-improving-upon-ggplotly-conversions/

Using sf 0.8-1 ; plotly 4.9.0 , ggplot2 3.2.0

My code:

```
library(sf) # m shapefiles
library(ggplot2) # graphics
library(plotly) # dynamic graphics
library(dplyr) # data-wrangling tidyverse
library(geobr) # download shapesfiles from Brazil (ibge)
library(sidrar) # download data (sidra)
library(rmapshaper) #  data-wrangling shapefiles
library(lubridate) # for dates

# download shapefiles from Brazilian States (UF) - IPEA geobr::
ufs <- geobr::read_state(code_state="all", year=2018)

# simplify the shapes rmapshaper::ms_simplify 
ufs <- rmapshaper::ms_simplify(ufs)

# download data from SIDRA - unemployment by state X quarter X gender
d <-sidrar::get_sidra(api = "/t/6396/n3/all/v/4099/p/all/c2/all/d/v4099%201")

# renaming columns
d <- d %>%  dplyr::mutate(date = `Trimestre (Código)`,
                          UF = `Unidade da Federação (Código)`)

# dates as dates
d$date <-lubridate::yq(d$date)

# selecting some quarters and only the total of both genders
d1 <- d %>%  dplyr::filter(Sexo == "Total" , date <= "2013-01-01") %>% 
             dplyr::select(UF, date, Valor)
d1$UF <- as.numeric(d1$UF)

# Joining geodata with unemployment rate, by = "uf"
ufs2 <- dplyr::full_join(ufs, d1, by = c("code_state" = "UF" ))

# plot map
m0<-ggplot2::ggplot(ufs2) +
                    geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = Valor, frame = date))

# map plotly::
m <- plotly::ggplotly(m0) %>%  
             style(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white"), hoveron = "fill")
m
```

The problematic result so far: 
[image: Gif in imgur]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work if you remove the x/y data from the frames as done in that blog post, so something like:

```
gg <- p %>%
  ggplotly() %>%
  style(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white"), hoveron = "fill") %>%
  plotly_build()

# remove x/y data from every trace
gg$x$frames <- lapply(
  gg$x$frames, function(f) { 
    f$data <- lapply(f$data, function(d) d[!names(d) %in% c("x", "y")])
    f 
  })
gg
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it worked fine! I failed to recognize what was the poupose of that part of your code.

Comment: I ´ve tried this part of the code and for some reason it didn't work that time. (Error in st_coordinates.sfc(model$geometry) : not implemented for objects of class sfc_GEOMETRY). But now it did

Comment: @Carson No longer working with multiple polygons- only a single. There is an open GitHub issue (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1659)